# Identifying an irreducible circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, dc, analysis

How would you go about identifying an irreducible circuit? By irreducible, I mean combining resistors whether in series or in parallel to reduce the circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the perspective of two given terminals in a circuit (e.g. output signal and ground), any linear circuit can be reduced to a Thevenin equivalent, which only consist of a single voltage source and a single resistor. Wikipedia has a fairly decent article with good examples:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thevenins_theorem

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct, [Here's an Example](https://www.physicsforums.com/proxy.php?image=https%3A%2F%2Ffarm9.staticflickr.com%2F8200%2F8236711208_093498af9d_z.jpg&hash=c4240ea8b82361506b4030c4c8094b24) of an irreducible network (IE a circuit which cannot be simplified, you'll need to you nodal analysis).

I am however also unclear how exactly you determine whether a netwrok is irreducible or not.

EDIT: Wheatstone bridge is another example of an irreducible network